# jquery mobile angularjs adapter

Tags: jquery-mobile, angularjs

I'm using [jquery-mobile-angular-adapter](https://github.com/tigbro/jquery-mobile-angular-adapter). This is my head of html document. I'm getting this kind error: `Object #<Object (angular)> has no method 'widget'.`

```
<head>
        <title>TEST</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jqm-1.1.0.structure.css" />

        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="scripts/lib/jquery.js"></script>        

        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="scripts/lib/jquery.mobile.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="scripts/lib/angular.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="scripts/lib/jquery-mobile-angular-adapter.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="scripts/lib/require.js" data-main="main"></script>      
</head>
```

Does anynone knows why?

Answer (score 0):

To me seens that you are using an old version of adapter. If I'm not wrong, angular droped 'widget' in 0.9.x

Comment: I'm using `jQuery Mobile angularJS adaper v1.0.6`. It is the latest version.

Comment: No, it is from 6 months ago, the latest version is 1.1.0 https://raw.github.com/tigbro/jquery-mobile-angular-adapter/master/compiled/jquery-mobile-angular-adapter-1.1.0.js